# Oracle SQL Union/Merge With Duplicates Issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, user-defined-functions

Hopefully someone can help me out.

So let's say I have temporary table named "TEMP_TABLE"

```
 EMP_ID     number
 EMP_FNAME  varchar2()
 EMP_LNAME  varchar2()
```

Records in "TEMP_TABLE"

```
1, Some, Guy
2, Some, Girl
3, Some, Animal
```

Through some SQL magic, I'm not going to delve into, those values are calculated and put into the TEMP_TABLE, the multiset of the a `select * from TEMP_TABLE` that is returned by a function

Let's say that function is `FUNC_THAT_RETURNS_TABLE`

Okay, so if I say `Select * from table("FUNC_THAT_RETURNS_TABLE");`

I am returned:

```
  1, Some, Guy
  2, Some, Girl
  3, Some, Animal
```

So far so good.

So now I create another table called `"NEWLY_CREATED_TABLE"`

By saying:

```
 Create Table "NEWLY_CREATED_TABLE" AS
 (Select * FROM table("FUNC_THAT_RETURNS_TABLE"));
```

Note that the table is created from querying the function

So those three records should now be inside of NEWLY_CREATED_TABLE

**The issue is that
If I say:**

```
Select * FROM NEWLY_CREATED_TABLE
Union
SELECT * FROM table("FUNC_THAT_RETURNS_TABLE");
```

The result set is:

```
 1, Some, Guy
 1, Some, Guy
 2, Some, Girl
 2, Some, Girl
 3, Some, Animal
 3, Some, Animal
```

Even though though the data is exactly the same, can somebody tell me what I'm missing?

I found the union issue when testing the possibility of using a merge.
When I am trying to merge the data on the table, with the data from the function, all of the data in the table is being replaced. Which lead me to think that the code isn't identifying the unique records properly.

My merge code:

```
 Merge Into Newly_Created_Table a
 using
 (
   Select * from table(Func_That_Returns_TABLE)
 ) b
On (a.EMP_ID = b.EMP_ID)

When Matched....

When Not Matched....
```

** EDIT ** 
9-7-2016 SHOUTOUT TO @Shannon Severance there was an empty space in one of the columns.

Are there any methods besides attempting to trim before an insert, truncate, or using a trigger before an insert to trim the :NEW value, to ensure that trailing white spaces won't be added for no apparent reason?

Comment: Data probably isn't the same. My first guess would be trailing whitespace in one, not the other. Doing a dump on the columns for each may be worthwhile. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm

Comment: @ShannonSeverance you were right, there was an empty space inserted into one of my columns. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for you. I ran that and did not get any error.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table
(
 EMP_ID     NUMBER,
 EMP_FNAME  varchar2(32),
 EMP_LNAME  varchar2(32)
);

INSERT INTO temp_table values (1, 'SOME','Guy');
INSERT INTO temp_table values (2, 'SOME','Girl');
INSERT INTO temp_table values (3, 'SOME','Animal');

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE three_values_ot AS OBJECT
   (
 EMP_ID     NUMBER,
 EMP_FNAME  varchar2(32),
 EMP_LNAME  varchar2(32)
   );


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE three_values_nt
   IS TABLE OF three_values_ot;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_THAT_RETURNS_TABLE
   RETURN three_values_nt
IS
   l_return three_values_nt := 
      three_values_nt (three_values_ot (1, 'SOME','Guy'),
                       three_values_ot (2, 'SOME','Girl'),
                       three_values_ot (3, 'SOME','Animal'));
BEGIN
   RETURN l_return;
END;

SELECT * FROM temp_table
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE (FUNC_THAT_RETURNS_TABLE ());
```

Output of above union query is

```
1   SOME    Guy
2   SOME    Girl
3   SOME    Animal
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. My original issue was that there was invisible whitespace in my string. Once I fixed that, I was good to go.